# Event not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
this.$root.find(".thread-vote-item").click( function() {
    var current_value = self.getCurrentValue();
    if(current_value !== null || current_value !== '' ) {
        self.enableButton(current_value);
    } 
    self.disableButton($(this).data('label'));

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#base-url").val() + '/thread/submit-vote',
        type: 'post',
        data: {thread_id: self.thread_id, vote: current_value},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                self.setCurrentValue(current_value);
                self.triggerChangedVoteEvent();
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

The click event does not work
but if i change to become lik ethis

```
$(".thread-vote-item").click( function() {
    var current_value = self.getCurrentValue();
    if(current_value !== null || current_value !== '' ) {
        self.enableButton(current_value);
    } 
    self.disableButton($(this).data('label'));

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#base-url").val() + '/thread/submit-vote',
        type: 'post',
        data: {thread_id: self.thread_id, vote: current_value},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                self.setCurrentValue(current_value);
                self.triggerChangedVoteEvent();
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

It works. What is the difference between $(selector) and $(selector).find();

this.$root comes from another $(selector).find

Comment: Here you go - it's explained on the jQuery help pages - https://api.jquery.com/find/  and https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: then what should i do to attach listener to .find ?

Comment: `find(xyz).click()` should work fine.  If it doesn't, there must be some other bug in your code.  Try this for example:   http://jsbin.com/pacuyekafu/edit?html,js,output  (open the console and click on `Test one`)

Comment: wow thanks, i just realise it works when i create a command to click  from console, but it does not work from the code it self